# WINAPI window not showing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

So I am a college student who is working with OpenGL this semester and trying to use WINAPI to show a window as per the class instructions. I follow step for step the code that the professor has given and the code runs with no errors, but when I run it in debug mode I don't get to see the console or window that I am telling visual studios to display. This is in Visual Studio 2019 using c++. I know that the code is correct as I've seen it run on the professors machine. I am wondering if anyone knew what was going on.

```
#include "Main.h"
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   //callbacks for winapi
   switch (msg)
   {
   case WM_CLOSE:
       DestroyWindow(hwnd);
       break;
   case WM_DESTROY:
       PostQuitMessage(0);
       break;
   case WM_KEYDOWN:
       if (wParam == 27)
       {
           PostQuitMessage(0);
       }
       break;
   default:
       return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
       break;
   }
   return 0;
}
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
   //Initialize Window ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma region Window Initialization
   if (AllocConsole())
   {
       FILE* stream;
       _wfreopen_s(&stream, TEXT("CONIN"), TEXT("rb"), stdin);
       _wfreopen_s(&stream, TEXT("CONOUT"), TEXT("wb"), stdout);
       _wfreopen_s(&stream, TEXT("CONIN"), TEXT("rb"), stderr);
   }

   WNDCLASSEX wc; //Window information Container
   wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
   wc.style = 0;
   wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
   wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
   wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
   wc.hInstance = hInstance;
   wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(wc.hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_ICON);
   wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
   wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
   wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
   wc.lpszClassName = L"MEWINDOW";
   wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wc.hInstance, (LPCTSTR)IDI_ICON);

   if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
   {
       MessageBox(NULL, L"Window registration failed!", L"Error!!!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
       exit(0);
       return E_FAIL;
   }

   DWORD dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
   DWORD dwWindowStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;

   RECT rc = { (long)0, (long)0, (long)600, (long)600 };
   AdjustWindowRectEx(&rc, dwWindowStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);

   LPCWSTR windowName = L"OpenGL - Window";

   HWND hWindowHandler = CreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,
       L"MEWINDOW",
       windowName,
       dwWindowStyle | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
       100, 100,
       600, 600,
       NULL, NULL,
       hInstance,
       NULL);
   if (hWindowHandler == NULL)
   {
       MessageBox(NULL, L"Window creation failed!", L"Error!!!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
       exit(0);
       return E_FAIL;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWindowHandler, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWindowHandler);
#pragma endregion

   //OpenGL Init ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma region OpenGL Initialization
#pragma endregion

   //Shader Compilation ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma region Shader Initialization
#pragma endregion

   //Shape Configuration ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma region Shape Initialization
#pragma endregion

   //Game Loop ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma region Game Loop
#pragma endregion

   std::cout << "Hello World\n";
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's your [message loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows)?

Comment: @rustyx This is the code that the professor is running in the video and he is getting a console saying "Hello World" and a blank white window that we initialized

Comment: @Ron unfortunately we are told to use the code base that I had provided in the question. Which is why I am confused why nothing is showing up

Comment: Do you have a resource file included in your project, containing an icon with the `IDI_ICON` identifier? If not, then that will likely cause your program not to run.

Comment: @RyanXLVI without a [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#creating-a-message-loop), your `WndProc` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

```
    _wfreopen_s(&stream, TEXT("CONIN"), TEXT("rb"), stdin);
    _wfreopen_s(&stream, TEXT("CONOUT"), TEXT("wb"), stdout);
```

The names are all missing the `'$'` at the end. They should be `"CONIN$"` and `"CONOUT$"` instead, see [Console Handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-handles) for more details.

```
    _wfreopen_s(&stream, TEXT("CONIN"), TEXT("rb"), stderr);
```

Change that to `"CONOUT$"` and `"wb"` instead, you don't want to open `stderr` in read mode for input. The `"b"` part is assuming you really want to use the standard I/O streams in binary mode.

The code should basically work with the changes above, as long as you build it as a Unicode GUI app. That said, it's unusual and unadvised to mix generic text code (`TEXT(...)`, `CreateWindowEx` etc) with Unicode-only code (`wWinMain`, `_wfreopen_s` etc).

---

[ *EDIT* ] The comments in the code about *OpenGL* and *game loop* suggest that there might be a message loop elsewhere in the real code. But for just the posted snippet to fully work, it's enough to modify the `WM_KEYDOWN` handler to close the GUI, and add a simple message loop in `wWinMain`.

```
   case WM_KEYDOWN:
       if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
           DestroyWindow(hwnd);
       break;
```

```
    for(MSG msg; GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0); )
    {   TranslateMessage(&msg); DispatchMessage(&msg); }

    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    getchar();
```

With the above, the app will open both the console and GUI windows, will wait for `ESC` to be pressed in the GUI, then print `Hello World` and wait for an Enter key in the console.